# Setting a new background image for UIButton programmatically in a ContainerViewController Class DEPENDING on which PARENT View it is In

Tags: ios, swift

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if (self.parent?.isKind(of: GuideViewController.self))!{

        relatedGuide1.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ab-logo-rebrand"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

I tried writing it in viewDidLoad as well. No cigar. It is strange because I am able to do this

```
@IBAction func relatedGuidePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if (self.parent?.isKind(of: GuideViewController.self))!{
    show(guideViewController, sender: nil)

    }

}
```

This top method basically shows a different view Controller depending on which parent it's in. For reference basically I have 7 view controllers all with the same layout but different data being displayed. So I figured a ContainerView would be the best way to go about it. Everything's been going swell but this is the last piece of the puzzle. Ideally I would js be able to do something more efficient than a bunch of conditional statements on a button but this is the best I've come up with so far.

Pour conclure: UIButton in a ContainerView. I want the UIButton to change (visually and functionally) depending on which ParentView it is in.

If anyone could help. Bless

Comment: Could you post your entire class?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys so I found an answer. It has to do with the view hierarchy and which callback gets called when, which I'm not going to get into (mostly because I might be wrong in my explanation) BUT you do need to implement the code in the viewDidAppear NOT viewWillAppear method. Here it is as follows:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {



    if (self.parent?.isKind(of: IDController.self))!{

    UpNextButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "536BA1")
    nextUpButtonImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo")


        //BUTTONS
        relatedGuideButton1.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "400080") //purple
        relatedGuideButton1.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "onenote-logo"), for: .normal)
        relatedGuideButton1.setTitle("TAKE NOTES", for: .normal) }
```

If you need some functionality along with the button that's a bit more straightforward. Just use the same conditional and implement like any other IBAction. Like thus:

```
 @IBAction func relatedGuideButton1Pressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if (self.parent?.isKind(of: IDController.self))!{

        show(notesController, sender: nil)
    }

    else if (self.parent?.isKind(of: DriveController.self))! ||
            (self.parent?.isKind(of: ShareController.self))! ||
            (self.parent?.isKind(of: NoteController.self))! ||
            (self.parent?.isKind(of: AppsController.self))! ||
            (self.parent?.isKind(of: SymbolsController.self))! ||
            (self.parent?.isKind(of: MonthController.self))! {

            show(guideViewController, sender: nil)

    }

}
```

Cheers!